# How to use ULIDs as ids in Beanie ODM

Tags: python, mongodb

I gave it a try, but it errors out, unable to encode it even when I tried to encode it in the code above:

```py
# fields.py
from typing import Dict, Any

from pydantic import Field
from ulid import ULID


def ulid_str_encoder(value: ULID):
    return str(value)


class ULIDStr(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: Any) -> 'ULIDStr':
        if not isinstance(v, ULID):
            raise ValueError("Invalid ULID")
        return cls(str(v))

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        field_schema.update(type="string", format="ulid", pattern="^[0-9A-Za-z]{26}$")
```

```py
# models
from typing import Optional

import ulid
from beanie import Document, Indexed
from pydantic import Field, EmailStr, validator

from xxxx.common.dataproviders.beanie.common.mixins import TimestampMixin
from xxxx.core.pydantic.fields import ULIDStr, ulid_str_encoder


class User(Document, TimestampMixin):
    id: ULIDStr = Field(default_factory=ulid.new, primary_key=True)
    email: Indexed(EmailStr, unique=True)
    password: str = Field(..., min_length=8, description="The user's hashed password")

    class Beanie:
        document_model_name = "users"

    class Config:
        bson_encoders = {
            ULIDStr: ulid_str_encoder
        }
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

tried this as well

```
    class Config:
        bson_encoders = {
            ulid.ULID: str
        }
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

same error:

```
api  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/beanie/odm/utils/encoder.py", line 198, in _encode
api  |     raise ValueError(errors)
api  | ValueError: [TypeError("'ULID' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```